# Evaluating an XPath with document.evaluate() to get an array of nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

**The Problem Statement:**

> Filter all nodes with an existing attribute that starts with a specific string (`temp` for example purposes). Print an array of node string representations as a result.

**The Code:**

```js
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var node = result.iterateNext(); 
var nodes = [];
while (node) {
  nodes.push(node);
  node = result.iterateNext();
}
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

The code is a bit bulky for such a straightforward problem. Is there a simpler and a more concise way to get an array of nodes from a `document.evaluate()` result?

Comment: That's how it is. You can remove one line inside the loop `node = result.iterateNext();` by moving the assignment from `var node;` to `while ((node = result.iterateNext())) {` which is a dubious practice though.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, I was afraid to be told that. Alright, please consider adding the statement as an answer, thanks!

Comment: this is really frustrating if you want to get the n'th element as a one-liner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a method to directly turn it into an array -- `Array.from` doesn't work, eg.  The best I could achieve was a little cleanup:

```js
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var node, nodes = []
while (node = result.iterateNext())
  nodes.push(node);

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a slightly more concise way of filling a new array with values from a snapshot:

```js
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

var nodes = Array.from({ length: result.snapshotLength }, (_, index) => result.snapshotItem(index));
    
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be a way to get the results directly from `document.evaluate()`.

Taking the concept from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600459/1575353), one could get [a snapshot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Snapshots) result, create an array [filled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) with dummy values (e.g. `0`s) and then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls to [snapshotItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMXPathResult#snapshotItem()).

```js
const query = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
const results = Array(query.snapshotLength).fill(0).map((element, index) =>  query.snapshotItem(index));
console.log(results);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

While less of a functional programming approach, one could also just use a *for* loop:

```js
const query = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (var i=0, results = []; i< query.snapshotLength; results.push(query.snapshotItem(i++)));
console.log(results);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

Additionally, given the last example of [*Equivalent constructs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop#Equivalent_constructs), the *while* loop could be rewritten as a *for* loop as well:

```
for ( ; condition; ) {
    statements;
}
```

So the original code could be written as such:

```
var nodes = [];
for(var node = result.iterateNext(); node; node = result.iterateNext()) {
    nodes.push(node);
}
```

See this demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var nodes = [];
for(var node = result.iterateNext(); node; node = result.iterateNext()) {
  nodes.push(node);
}

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

#### Performance Comparison

Compare the four approaches with [this jsperf example](https://jsperf.com/pushingnodes). In Chrome, Firefox, and MS Edge it reports that the original code is the fastest.